# Laravel polymorphic voting system with namespaces

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm attempting to add what I hope is a simple voting module to posts and comments. A "Connection" is a type of post in my application. Users can vote up or down a Connection, or a Comment.

The issue I'm running into is when I attempt to attach a vote to a Connection. I receive this error: `Class name must be a valid object or a string`.

Here's the line of code in question:

```
$voteToCast = $vote->voteable()->associate($voteable);
```

I am certain the $voteable `var` is an instance of an Ardent/Eloquent model, so I can only presume the error lies within the way I am namespacing my models, or some pathetic typo I am too blind to see. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Connection Model (type of post):

```
...

public function votes()
{
    return $this->morphMany('Acme\Votes\Vote', 'voteable');
}
```

And the Votes Model:

```
/* Votes Model */

namespace Acme\Votes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use LaravelBook\Ardent\Ardent;

class Vote extends Ardent {

    protected $table = 'votes';

    protected $fillable = [
        'value',
        'votable_id',
        'voteable_type'
    ];

    /**
     * Establish the polymorphic relationship
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function voteable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Acme\\Users\\User');
    }

    /**
     * Vote the item up
     *
     * @param Model $voteable
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function up(Model $voteable)
    {
        return (new static)->cast($voteable, 1);
    }

    /**
     * Vote the item down
     *
     * @param Model $voteable
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function down(Model $voteable)
    {
        return (new static)->cast($voteable, -1);
    }

    /**
     * Execute the vote
     *
     * @param Model $voteable
     * @param int $value
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function cast(Model $voteable, $value = 1)
    {
        if (!$voteable->exists) return false;

        $vote = new static;
        $vote->value = $value;

        $voteToCast = $vote->voteable()->associate($voteable);
        $voteToCast->save();
    }

    /**
     * Restrict the votes so the absolute value is 1
     *
     * @param $value
     */
    public function setValueAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['value'] = ($value == -1) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Votes Controller:

```
...

public function cast($connection)
{

    $voteable = Connection::findOrFail($connection);

    if (Input::get('value' < 1)){
        return Vote::down($voteable);
    }

    return Vote::up($voteable);

}
```

Comment: Have you tried var_dump or print_r to verify that your variables contain what you think they do?

Comment: Hi @SimonSvensson, thanks for your response. Yes, I have been inspecting things at just about every relevant point I can think of using Xdebug. I think as far as I can tell, the pieces are in place. Is there a specific variable(s) you'd suggest I verify?

Comment: I just tested it with all your code on a locale instance of laravel and it all worked flawlessly. Does the stack trace contain any useful information?

Comment: @jakeharris Use the stack trace and check where that error happens..

Comment: Thanks for checking in guys! 

Unfortunately the stack trace just records an immediate shutdown:

`1. Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
…/­vendor/­laravelbook/­ardent/­src/­LaravelBook/­Ardent/­Ardent.php382
0. Illuminate\Exception\Handler handleShutdown
<#unknown>0`

Answer (score 0):

After some more troubleshooting, this appears to be an issue with the way Ardent handles relationships. I was able to use Eloquent on my Vote model instead of Ardent and the voting mechanism now works flawlessly.